# Javascript passing int[] to java api

Tags: arrays, int

I'm trying to call a Java api from Javascript, but one parameter in the Java method is an int[] - I'm struggling to create the appropriate type in Javascript.

Java version 1.6

I've read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/prog_guide/javascript.html) but I think this would only work in java 8 - my java 6 doesn't seems to support Java.type() as a call.

var a = new int[3];   <-- passes Array

var a = Java.type("int[]");   <--  (Java not found)

var a = Packages.Java.type("int[]");   <--  (Packages.Java not found)

Worst case I can wrap this api in java & handle the conversion myself, but I suspect I'll end up finding more and more method calls that contain primitives & it's a large api so I'd rather not end up wrapping every method call.

Thanks

Comment: did you import your Java library?

Comment: Yes, because I am calling Packages.java.util.ArrayList etc with no issue.  I should have said that [Packages.]java.type("int[]"); also fails.  I believe that's because Java.type() is provided by a higher java/JS version.  My JS is embedded in a product & have struggled to find it's version to see if it is compliant with JSR 223.